# 60 sec. shutdown delay in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shutdown

Is there any resonable reason why the 60 sec delay pops up when I press the shutdown button ?

I press the shutdown button to shutdown, if i want to restart, I just press the "turn on" button when the PC has shut down, that aint hard.

Can I get rid of the delay ? I do not see any reason why it is there ????

Comment: Start up and shutdown are hard on hardware, especially the more expensive and more powerful systems so the 'turn on after pc has shut down' is a big no-no on a larger expensive systems. I like the delay anyway on the DEsktop; as if I want an immediate shutdown I just `sudo shutdown -h now`...  (*have you noticed you have to add the -h to halt the hardware; to force it off! to avoid accidentally turning it off given the potential $cost on larger systems*)

Comment: In earlyer Ubuntu's you could remove it by typing this in a terminal  "gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-logout-restart-shutdown true" But it does not work in 18.04

Answer (score 2):

That's built into Ubuntu as automatic protection just in case you inadvertently press the power button and eg, forgot to save a file. To override this, `sudo poweroff` gives an immediate response as does `sudo reboot` (restart).

Comment: "sudo poweroff" will meen that i have to start a terminal. Just want to shutdown nothing else. I would be ok if the popup came, if ther was open windows or unsavet things, but there isn't.

Comment: Even in Windows, it's not recommended you shutdown via the power button other than in emergency, else you could corrupt it. I suppose you could flick the PSU switch if you are that intent on immediate shutdown in Ubuntu.  But what's wrong with using the standard shutdown procedure?

Comment: What's wrong, is just that i have to confirm a task that i just did. When i press the power button i meens that i intend to shut down my computer, not that i need to confirm that i want to shut down.It does not harm the computer, as i shuts down in the exact same way, just like when i confirm i want to shut down. But i have found the solution. In "dconf-editor" i found the setting, that prevents the popup box :-)

Answer (score 2):

My solution involves the following steps:

1. Use `dconf-editor` or `gsettings` to stop sending the power-off events to Gnome
2. Create a custom event handler as outlined in the `acpi` examples

To turn off event handling by Gnome:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power nothing
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action nothing
```

Now to create the custom event handler for the power button (do the following as root):

In folder `/etc/acpi/events` create the event file.  I called mine `button-power` with the following contents:

```
event=button[ /-]power
action=/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh "%e"
```

The bit in braces is `regexp` for "space, slash or dash".  If you're confident your kernel supplies only slashes you can go with the explicit character.

In folder `etc/acpi` create the script file you referred to above (`powerbtn.sh`) with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/logger "Custom shutdown in response to event $1"
/sbin/shutdown -h now "Custom shutdown: $1"
```

Either reboot or send your `acpid` a `SIGHUP` and your power button will now instantly initiate a controlled shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

```
gsettings set org.mate.session logout-timeout 3
```

will set the timer to 3 seconds.

Comment: That's for MATE, not Gnome. If you didn't specifically install MATE, I don't think this is the solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [@Terrible Tadpole](https://askubuntu.com/users/462687/terrible-tadpole)'s answer.
But what worked on my Ubuntu 22.04 install.

**1. Disable Ubuntu's/Gnome's Setting. (if not already)**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action nothing
```

**2. Create acpi Action for Power Button Event.**

In folder `/etc/acpi/events` create a file with a name that is not already taken
(Example Filename: `power-button-fast-shutdown`) an with the following Content:

```
event=button/power
action=/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

(if not familiar with terminal file handling start the editor from terminal: `sudo gedit` or file manager `sudo nautilus`)

Comment: And afterwards restart the ACPI daemon: `sudo service acpid restart`